# MongoDB C# Driver: What happens exactly when I execute a query?

Tags: c#, mongodb, performance

I'm comparing the performance of a MongoDB solution with other database models, so I need to get some accurate timing information when executing queries.

(In my case, using the MongoDB C# driver,) when I execute `Find` or `FindAsync`, what exactly happens on the server-side and what data gets passed through? Did the server *execute* the query and is the only thing that happens when, for example, I do `ToList()` on that cursor, transferring the documents over the network?

Or is the query only executed (entirely or partly) when I actually want to retrieve the documents? Or maybe, some kind of information about the results are already transferred with the call to`Find`?

Answer (score 0):

`Find` and `FindAsync` both allows to build asynchronous query with the same performance, only:

When you `FindAsync`, it returns cursor which **doesn't load all documents at once**, but **provides you interface to retrieve documents one by one** from DB cursor (it's helpful in case when query result is huge).

Method `Find` provides you more simple syntax through method `ToListAsync` where it **inside retrieves documents from cursor and returns all documents at once**.

But neither `Find` nor `FindAsync` does not retrieve any data from server, until you asked for it (iteration by cursor).

Hope, it helps.

Comment: Sorry, apparently my question wasn't entirely clear. (though what you explained is definitely interesting and good to know, so thanks!) I meant to ask what processing the *server* has already done, i.e. has the query already been executed when we get a cursor back, or is it executed when the first document is retrieved?

Comment: Server does nothing until you asked for the first document. So, in your words - "it's executed when the first document is retrieved".